# Is it fine to add a custom label inside a gallery to reference its text that will be used inside the other elements properties?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a gallery and i want to color code some elements and show/hide some elements based on the result of the following formula:-

```
If(ThisItem.'Contract Type'.Value = "Out of Home" And !ThisItem.HasPrintSheetSync And IsEmpty(Filter('Client Exclude List',Title=ThisItem.Client)) And ThisItem.FinanceActionSync=false,"Red",If(!IsEmpty(Filter('Client Exclude List',Title=ThisItem.Client)),"Green"))
```

Since the formula will initiate calls to the backend, so i do not want to repeat this formula multiple times, so what i did is that i added a label named "colorCodeForView" inside the gallery >> and inside the label's Text property I added the above formula, as follow:-

[image: johnjohn123_0-1698791747955.png]

then inside the other gallery's elements i reference the Label's text property as follow:-

[image]

now it is working well, on my windows machine, but not sure if this is a valid approach? if not, then what is the alternative i have?

Thanks